# How to stop an iPhone (not in my possession) from air playing to my Mac?

Tags: macos

I used to use the paid software AirServer, but after updating to Monterey, Apple made it possible to do this without 3rd party software.

My wife uses it all the time. My Mac mini is integrated into our entertainment center and is connected to the stereo. She was air playing some music this evening, but after awhile, she went downstairs to take a shower and left it playing. I decided to watch some TV.

With airserver, all I had to do was close the window that would show up during the airplay session, so I closed the window that showed my wife's phone screen. The screen went away, but the audio kept going.

I poked around in all the menus (mirroring, audio, control center), looked in the audio system preferences (audio, displays). All the google results talked about stopping airplaying from the audio source device. Nothing talked about how to stop it from the receiving device.

I couldn't figure it out. I gave up and rebooted the computer.

Was this a bug or did I overlook the control somewhere?

Comment: The control to stop a remote device is located in the "Now Playing" section of Control Center. You can also configure the control to appear in the menu bar, if you wish (open System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Now Playing and enable "Show in Menu Bar").

Comment: OK, I see what happened... I just tried this out and confirmed your solution, however that menu (triangle in a circle) was not there yesterday, and I had a hunch why - which I also just tested and confirmed... I still have AirServer installed and running.  And apparently in Monterey, AirServer behaves slightly differently. Closing the window doesn't stop it... though it's possible I'm misremembering how it used to behave.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out. Could you to rewrite your comment into an answer? That'd be a great help to others who have a similar issue. You can then accept your own answer.

Comment: I feel like I'd prefer to confirm how AirServer worked before. I bet I'm forgetting that I used to just quit and restart it. But I just don't remember audio continuing after closing the window.